# Not able to remove added view to status bar in android

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager

I am trying to block status bar and I am successful in doing that by adding a view to status bar. I am trying to remove the added view when onClick is detected, but the view still remains and I am not able to remove the view. Can any one please let me know what am I missing. The current code is as shown below:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

     localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

                // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

                // Draws over status bar
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

        localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        localLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
        localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

         view = new customViewGroup(this);

        manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);

//      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
//                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        m_activateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        m_activateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 if(manager != null){
                        manager.removeView(view);
                        }
                }});



     }
```

CustomView Class:

```
public class customViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    public customViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.v("customViewGroup", "**********Intercepted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to do this on a runonUIThread as follows : this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                manager.removeView(view);
            }
        }); otherwise instead of manager, you can try : `((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(view);`

Comment: Explain a little bit, you have tried my code and it's giving any error?

Comment: @Skizo I have tried it, not able to remove view and no error either. If I try to use the same lines used in onCreate and if I say manager.removeView() it says view is not attached to Window.

Comment: Post your customView pls

Comment: @Skizo Updated code with customView class

Comment: Can you create a gist or something, I've tried your code and I can't see any changes, what I need to see when button is clicked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88679/discussion-between-skizo-and-keshav1234).

Comment: Gist means?? when button is clicked i am navigating to default settings activity of android, there I need to remove this view.